# What does cutting parts off of creatures accomplish?

Tags: dauntless

Commonly, you can cut the tails off of creatures when fighting them. Does this give you some sort of bonus or is it a cool visual effect? (e.g. Bonus damage or bonus loot)

Are there any drawbacks from cutting the tails off creatures? (e.g. Different loot-pools)

Comment: Is this actually playable right now?

Comment: @Frank It's playable with the purchase of a founder's pack, yes.

Comment: @Fluttershy or being lucky and get invited to the CBT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was watching a stream today and according to them,

- Chopping off body parts can have a **combat effect** (e.g. Gnasher's tail can no longer be used for combat once chopped off, obviously)
- Chopping off body parts can have a **loot effect** (i.e. Copping off parts drops an orb of some sort that gives you a generic loot item from the monster).
- There is no apparent effect or bonus for not chopping off a body part.

Comment: I play the game myself, and this is basically it. Also you don't do extra damage to chopped off/damaged body parts.

Comment: That's why I said combat effect instead of bonus, but that's not super obvious I guess :P